# Как проверить переменную на пустоту AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

На странице имеется текстовое поле для отправки сообщения. 
Как сделать проверку в контроллере на пустоту поля, ввел ли пользователь сообщение или нет. 
Сообщение отправляется по enter: `ng-enter="sendMessage()"`

Думаю, что прежде чем проверять на пустоту, нужно сделать `trim()`

Comment: А просто `if(!$scope.enter){...}` не подходит?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
angular.equals("", $scope.enter)
```